# Fast way to find bit length of large positive integer from decimal

Tags: python, integer, bit

Given the decimal string representation of a large positive integer, what's a fast way to find the integer's bit length? Using `int()` and then `bit_length()` is slow. This example with a million digits takes over five seconds to tell me it has 3321926 bits:

```
s = '1234567890' * 10**5
print(int(s).bit_length())
```

Result should be exact, at least for all strings one can actually have in memory (so let's say up to up to 100 billion decimal digits).

Comment: What else have you tried? How does `round(log(number)/log(2) + 1)` perform?

Comment: Each decimal digit is 3.322 bits.  So, `int(len(s)*3.322)` is pretty darned close.

Comment: @TimRoberts Like I said, I want *exact*, for numbers up to billions of digits.

Comment: @RandomDavis What's `number`? Remember, given is a *string*.

Comment: Then you need to pay the price of converting to int.  You might have a serious conversation with yourself to decide whether a difference of  2 parts per billion really has any meaning.

Comment: It's the conversion to int that takes time. After all, since the digits *don't* correspond to a set number of bits, it has to do tedious math. Where exactly does your string input come from? Or is this only a theoretical problem?

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm not convinced I do. And even then, there might be faster ways to do it than with `int()`.

Comment: How much variation is there in the length of the strings?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It's inspired by another question, which made me realize I don't know a *fast* way to do it, but wouldn't be surprised if there were one. So, theoretical.

Comment: You've got a lot of RAM if you're keeping a 100 billion character string in memory.

Comment: @user2357112 Just 100 GB. I know someone who got a PC with 256 GB about 10 years ago.

Comment: @KellyBundy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1309123/6273251) is an existing post about this exact topic. Can you explain why your question is not a duplicate of that one?

Comment: @RandomDavis: That question is about 32-bit integers. This question is about 100-billion-digit integers. The algorithmic requirements for such sizes are very different.

Answer (score 2):

If storage space is not an issue and you don't mind spending time up-front, (and you'd rather have a solution that doesn't depend on floating point accuracy, even if it's otherwise impractical) you can solve just about any speed issue with more memory. Build a lookup table of the string representations of `2**n`. Set up a dictionary, keying the string length to a list of (string of that length, corresponding n value) pairs. To test an input, look up the appropriate list, and then use ordinary string comparison to figure out which bit-length category it's in.

Comment: You mean store all `2**n` for n up to 300 billion? With an average of 150 billion bits, that sounds like 6 trillion GB total. Not exactly realistic :-). For just up to a million decimal digits I think it's 60 GB, which is borderline. Also, preparing all this data also takes time.

Comment: That's why I gave the caveats that I did. You're the one, in this hypothetical, who has strings 100 billion characters long in the first place. Presumably multiple of them, if you care enough to do this kind of testing.

Comment: Ah, it is O(N^2) storage, though, fair point.

Answer (score 1):

This should be accurate for billions of digits, I think.  Calculate the exact result for 100000...00000 by simply bits-per-digit, then add the log of the first 10 digits.

```
import math

s = '1234567890' * 10**5

dper = math.log(10)/math.log(2)
base= (len(s)-10)*dper
extra = math.log(int(s[:10]))/math.log(2)
print(int(base+extra+0.99))
```

Comment: This is going to fail for numbers close-ish to a power of 2. The only information it looks at is the string length and the first 10 decimal digits, which isn't enough for an exact answer.

Comment: It will be exact with your one exception, off by one near powers of 2.

Comment: For random 20-digit numbers, this is [wrong about 1% of the time](https://tio.run/##ZVDNasMwDL77KXS0kzVLustSyGmPUUpJUzcxOHaQVdiePpPctAwmMEL6fvTh5YemGD4@F1zXG8YZhui9HcjFkMDNS0SCr3gPZFFlHPtw5bZBMvEbrdoWc0@TUgMhdE@dNkrdIsIZXIBM1k0tZQ4KuBxTXz4MFUXTvoH0fW0yIzEjEWr3GIeIyBF56aqLo7O3YaRJzgh6XawclyCVjyMbmvfXsH84XPpkO9As1MnsmFGIKkP2m7D/q3eBdDoemvpk/huhTXefkzBLXMusL@uqbbc8/BfHjbZ7Rj9B2UGj1IKiY4ZZ118).

Answer (score 1):

This does the example in about 0.15 seconds, and `'1234567890' * 10**6` in about 2 seconds and `'1234567890' * 10**7` in about 20 seconds. First I approximate the bit length with logarithms (similar to Tim's way), then I use [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) to adjust until exact. That class uses base 10, so it doesnt need a costly base conversion.

Bit length b covers the interval [2**(b-1), 2**b). So we want (the exponent of) the smallest power of 2 larger than the number.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFRb4IwEMff@ynuDYo6AefmzFiyOB980Cx7WrIsBqRKEyik3KL79OxoYWrsA/T@9/u3vbvqF7NSTWaVbpq9LgtAWQiQRVVqNHtm1CLGrFfz8hBaNRU7WcR5n/AYqwXuSoXihO6i@1da7KL16@f2/WO5GMKyiE8mXNKnDaWK1qsNhasN54ylYg@JxG0u1AEzt@ZzBrTkHkihEJ4jCH0rtksL/NEKpEJK3l04uUEyEadbUmuIzMNdA37NQ/@bWwJjmfeE290xois4eNYR@BZMCGjd5yMHZ7NFFCFvtiluJ1XlUegLOaRzPUhM7pjJXHTEC6hzUQmMIgj@Q0uMx1T5jY/acWUc3Bq93tf1KqE50YucIJzcTx8eZ0@@Q7UGvudNWY0xTTIyo6cWVrqt@GoevWgJapWxDMGpBY0@rR3eNH8)

```
from time import time
from math import log2
from decimal import *

setcontext(Context(prec=MAX_PREC, Emax=MAX_EMAX, Emin=MIN_EMIN))

def bit_length(s):
    if len(s) <= 20:
        return int(s).bit_length()
    head_bits = log2(int(s[:20]))
    tail_bits = (len(s) - 20) * log2(10)
    b = int(head_bits + tail_bits)
    n = Decimal(s)
    power = Decimal(2) ** b
    while power > n:
        b -= 1
        power //= 2
    while power <= n:
        b += 1
        power *= 2
    return b

s = '1234567890' * 10**5
start = time()
print(bit_length(s))
print(time() - start, 'seconds')
```

Comment: My `Decimal` example is 5x faster than this, I'm not sure why this is doing loops when just a couple of `log()` operations are needed

Comment: @RandomDavis Because I doubt that just using the logs is correct.

Comment: @RandomDavis It very well *could* be correct, and that's actually why I limited the required range for exactness in the question (to around 12 digits, less than `floats`'s ~16 digits precision). I'm just not convinced.

Comment: You're "not convinced" that logarithms are doing the exact thing they're designed to be used for in mathematics? The relationship between logarithms and the number of digits in a number has been mathematically proven long ago. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/231745) is an explanation. I think it's unreasonable to not trust that a built-in mathematical function is working as intended, or is imprecise. If you don't understand how or why logarithms work, then that means you should learn about them, not reject them.

Comment: @RandomDavis Your way to do the logs is better, though, I might adopt that. I had tried that but it was super slow, but probably that was because I had already maximized the precision setting.

Comment: @RandomDavis The issue is not about logarithms but about `float`s (or `Decimal`s).

Comment: (@RandomDavis's answer and our comments there got deleted, let me wrap up the discussion here instead) Turns out using just logs was indeed not correct, even with RandomDavis's way involving `Decimal(s).log10()`, i.e., potentially taking *all* digits into account for that instead of just the first 20 like I do. Sometimes the result was 1 too high and sometimes it was 1 too low, even for some very small numbers. Increasing the precision setting didn't help.